# Loop to get loction then start next loop

Tags: excel, vba

Amended.

Loop01, loop through column B to find the value "x", then use that value position as the starting point for the next loop. Loop02, loop through column B. If the value matches, put the "data" value in row 2, column D for D, E for E... If Loop02 finds the value "x", then start Loop02 again on a new row.

I have attached an image.

[image: See Image]

```
Sub Test()
Dim N As Long, i As Long, i2 As Long, j As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
j = 2
LD = Sheet1.Range("D1").Value
LE = Sheet1.Range("E1").Value
LF = Sheet1.Range("F1").Value
LG = Sheet1.Range("G1").Value
LH = Sheet1.Range("H1").Value
LI = Sheet1.Range("I1").Value
LJ = Sheet1.Range("J1").Value

For i = 2 To N
    If Cells(i, "B").Value = "x" Then
    i = i + 1
        For i2 = 2 To N
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = "x" Then
                i = i - 1
                j = j + 1
                Exit For
            End If
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = LD Then
                Cells(j, "D").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = LE Then
                Cells(j, "E").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = LF Then
                Cells(j, "F").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = LG Then
                Cells(j, "G").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = LH Then
                Cells(j, "H").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = LI Then
                Cells(j, "I").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            If Cells(i, "B").Value = LJ Then
                Cells(j, "J").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next i2
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: 1) When you ask for help to solve homework issues, it is fair to state so, in your question. Whoever answers can adjust the answer to be rather pedagogic instead of just a plain solution of your homework. 2) Here at Stack Overflow we value time. Please avoid "polite fluff" like your three first sentences. From [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "Pretend you are talking to a busy colleague". Start you post with a short summary of the problem, then expand as needed.

Comment: 3) *...and it didn't work, lol.* is a useless statement, if not immediately followed by an explanation what exactly was wrong. Since your simplified test data works, what do you expect anybody here to tell you to fix?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg, it is not homework, and yes, I see your point. I will update it and remove the "polite fluff". I don't want to just dump all my data and the formula I was using without showing the logic in a simpler fashion. But if it is ok? Then more than happy to drop a link to the workbook with all the data and formulas. It didn't work with the real data because "x" was a value that was needed, so if it replaces x with D, the value D is required and the first row, then the next row after that. I just explain it wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, maybe the sub below can get help you started.

```
Sub test()
Dim hdr As Range: Dim c As Range
Dim vHdr As Range: Dim ofst As Long: Dim rw As Long

Set hdr = Range("D1:J1")
rw = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ofst = 0
Set c = Columns(2).Find("x", lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not c Is Nothing Then
Set vHdr = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Do
    ofst = ofst + 1
        Do
        If vHdr <> "" Then _
            hdr.Find(vHdr.Value).Offset(ofst, 0).Value = _
                                    vHdr.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Set vHdr = vHdr.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop Until vHdr.Value = "x"
    Set vHdr = vHdr.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until vHdr.Row >= rw
End If

End Sub
```

It create the header range (where the result will be) into hdr variable.
Get the last row with value in column B into rw variable.
Make ofst variable value with zero to use for the offset value.
Find the first occurence of "x" in column B as c variable and use c.offset(1,0) as vHdr variable.

The first loop is to have the next "x", and to add the ofst value + 1 
The second loop check if the vHdr value is not blank then it get the cell in hdr via find method where the value to find is the vHdr value.

After it get the cell in hdr which has the vHdr value, it use the found cell offset with ofst value to write the value in vHdr.offset(0,-1).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the guidance. I will jump in add give it a go.